# Что за условие в цикле?

Tags: c, stm32

Что за условие в цикле или это опечатка?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот ссылка на статью с циклом в коде:
http://easyelectronics.ru/arm-uchebnyj-kurs-preryvaniya-i-nvic-prioritetnyj-kontroller-preryvanij.html

Comment: Опечатка. Этот код не скомпилируется

Comment: Это бессмысленный набор символов, а не "условие".